# Ordenação utilizando DbGrid com ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou utilizando um DbGrid juntamente com um DataSource.
E estou querendo fazer a ordenação conforme o cliente clicar no titulo. 
Fiz as seguintes configurações:
No meu Dbgrid na propriedade DataSource linkei o meu DS.
No meu Ds na propriedade DataSet eu linkei o meu ClientDataSet.
No ClientDataset no fields editor adicionei um field:

```
Name:cod_produto 
Type: Integer
Field type: Data
```

Tenho um botao buscar, nele eu faço a consulta em um tbQuery.

Minha duvida é como eu jogo esses dados da TbQuery para dentro do meu ClientDataSet, para que apareça no DbGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `DataSetProvider` ligado ao `TBQuery`, e na propriedade "ProviderName" do `ClientDataset` referenciá-lo.
Antes da busca, feche o CDS, reabrindo-o após a busca. Os dados estarão lá.

Answer (score 1):

Vá no evento onTitleClick e coloque:

```
if xOrdemAsc then
   RefazSQL(Column.FieldName + ' ASC')
else
   RefazSQL(Column.FieldName + ' DESC');

DBGrid1.OnDblClick := Nil;
```

na procedure de conculta coloque uma váriavel que receba estas colunas:

```
procedure TfCLI001.RefazSQL(pOrdem : String = 'NOME ASC');
```

após isso é só colocar no order by da consulta.

```
ibCLI001.SQL.Add('ORDER BY ' + pOrdem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz um while na sua tabela dando um append no seu ClientDataSet.

```
    while not tbQuery.eof do
    begin
      ClientDataSet.Append;
      ClientDataSet.FiedByName('NomeDoCampo').AsString :=
      tbQuery.FieldByName('NomeDoCampo').AsString; 
      ClientDataSet.Post;
      tbQuery.Next;
    end;
```

Comment: Pensei em fazer dessa forma, só queria saber se existe algum method que me retorne isso, tentei o method `MoveBy(-1)`, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Você pode usar o componente DataSetProvider ligado ao seu DataSet, no caso a sua Query. O DataSetProvider vai fazer a transferência de dados da Query para o ClientDataSet de forma dinâmica.